# CSS Media Query Screen orientation issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using this media query for target viewport max-width of 800px devices mininmum with of 400px

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-device-width: 400px)
{
body {background:#fff;}
}
```

And i need to change the color in the landscape orientation for this i use this code

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape)
{
body {background:red;}
}
```

its working good in the device but the background red applies for pc browsers also how to apply background red in devices landscape orientation only?

Thank you.

Comment: PCs are landscape, aren't they?

Comment: @GarethCornish : How to target handheld devices landscape ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't choosing an element to apply the background to

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape)
{background:red;}
```

Should be something like:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1000px) 
              and (orientation:landscape){
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

The max-device-width should make it ignore desktops, if you don't put `device` in there, it will still affect desktops that have made their browser smaller.

Comment: this won't fix the problem ;)

Comment: because the problem is that orientation affects also dekstops - you should do it the way that @Fabrizio Calderan did

Comment: @Andy : Updated my question but i need to target handheld devices orientation... in my case it affect pc also

Comment: @krish Updated, use `max-device-width`, not `max-width`

Answer (score 2):

try in this way

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) 
              and (min-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background: white;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) 
              and (min-width: 400px)
              and (orientation:landscape) {
    body {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

or try to detect handheld-only devices looking at the `min-resolution` value as in http://jsbin.com/irozuf/1/edit - e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) 
              and (min-width: 400px)
              and (min-resolution: 97dpi)   /* a typical screen has 96dpi */
              and (orientation:landscape) {
    body {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Looking at this [list of displays by pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density) it seems that it could work fine on modern mobile devices

Comment: This will still affect desktops if they make their browser smaller, try `max-device-width`

Answer (score 2):

if you add these meta tags to head of page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

so the key: "width" means same "device-width".so,

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1000px){}
```

is equal to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){}
```

use each one you like:
[meta tags with key "width"]
OR
[no meta tags but "device-width"]

Comment: I've changed my question a little, mata tag works finr for 'width', but don't use it for 'height'.